Building GCC 9.1.0 fails (make: *** [Makefile:1004: all] Error 2)
Coding newbie, I'm a researcher trying to get an air quality program to run. It requires GCC9.1.0, but during the make step I keep getting an error line:
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/(my name)/gcc-9.1.0/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1004: all] Error 2

Unsure what information would be helpful to the problem, VERY new to coding (I had a friend help me with getting to this point but he's also unsure what this means)
This is the site where the steps were specified: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC
Where the code says (my name) I just censored my actual name
Thanks so much!
Edit: Operating system is Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS
It seems like this is the only error message, and as far as I can tell the program I want needs this version. I have not gotten it to run though, with this version or any other.

Please [edit] your question and add your operating system. I also don't know much about this, but I do know that compiling gcc is not a trivial task, and changing the default gcc on a GNU system (which is what the make install command that comes later would do) is a very bad idea and not for the faint of heart. Are you sure you need to do this? Have you tried compiling the air quality program with the gcc version you currently have?  And isn't there any more information in the error? Can you add a few more lines from before and after what you show?

The line make: *** [Makefile:1004: all] Error 2 tells you that make was not able to build the (phony) target all which is on line 1004 of the Makefile. This was most likely caused by some error that occurred when building a prerequisite of all. You should look for more specific errors that occurred before.
Is GCC 9.1.0 not available as a pre-built package for your OS?

I improved the title based on the current information in the question.

You have not updated the question as asked by the comments. It is the few error messages people need, not the last.

What you are showing is the result of an earlier error. If you run the build again, there will be an error, then there will be some output from make reacting to the failed compile, and then make will say Error 2 as you show (which is just make's way of saying "I'm done here").  It's the first compiler errors from cc or gcc or similar, not make, that are interesting.

"Error 2" (ENOENT) means "No such file or directory".
Are you sure you have write access to the directory? Did the configure script complete successfully?

"as far as I can tell the program I want needs this version" I'd still encourage you to post a separate question about building the program you want with a version of GCC that's already available for your system. While gcc default behavior changes between versions, it's usually possible to emulate the behavior of an older version using the right combination of flags or options - and in my (admittedly limited) experience that's usually easier than building gcc from source. In the case of Ubuntu 24.04, the default GCC is 13.2.0 however GCC 9.5.0 is available from the Universe  repository.

... fwiw I tried the build myself, and discovered that this may be relevant Bug 105029 - sanitizer_internal_defs.h:254:72: error: size of array ‘assertion_failed__1135’ is negative
